# Bootstrap Modal Window pop-up after 5sec

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, settimeout, bootstrap-modal

Do anyone know how to make bootstrap modal window pop-up after 5sec ? 
I had done a Modal Window with auto pop up but I wish it's pop up delay 5 sec .
can anyone help ? 
thanks for help .
here my code .

```
            <div class="modal fade in" id="formSaludo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: block;">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                     <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                              <h5><strong>給我們一個小小的贊吧～我們會帶給你更多的趣事，新聞，最新動態！您的一個贊給我們帶來無限的力量！</strong></h5>
                              <img class="img-responsive center-block " src="funnylike.jpg">
                          </div> 
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/cloudsblacks" data-width="200" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>    </div> 
                            <div class="modal-footer">

                                  <a class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal" style="font-size:15px;color:#808080;cursor: pointer;text-decoration: none;">已經讚了,请稍等...</a>
                          </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>



   <!-- Modal Window -->           
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#formSaludo').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: use setTimeOut function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to do something like this

```
var show = function(){
    $('#formSaludo').modal('show');
};

$(window).load(function(){
    var timer = window.setTimeout(show,5000);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout

Comment: Hi Steve , thanks for your answer . I had tried but not work ,is my css blocking the function ? here my site cloudsblack.com/modalwindow.html , can you help me to look over ? thanks

Comment: try adding the attribute data-show='false' to modal html. the div with the id 'formSaludo'.

Answer (score 3):

Use **setTimeout()** function

```
$(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#formSaludo').modal('show'); }, 5000);

});
```

Comment: Hi Tamil Selvan , thanks for your answer . I had tried setTimeout() but not work ,is my css to block the function ? here my site cloudsblack.com/modalwindow.html , can you help me to look over ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#formSaludo').delay(5000).modal('show');
```

EDIT:

I'm not sure if the `delay` function will work in this case. You can always use `setTimeout` like others have suggested.

Comment: Hi pablochan , thanks for your answer . I had tried but not work ,here my site http://www.cloudsblack.com/modalwindow.html  , can you help me to look over ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
setTimeout(function(){
$('#formSaludo').modal(); }, 
5000);
```

Hope it will be work.